# User cron job permission denied to directory owned by the user

Tags: raspbian, cron, permissions

I am using Raspbian Jessie. I have a `cron` job for `pi` user as follows:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
@reboot /path/to/execute_script.sh
```

The script I am executing involves creating directories on a mounted USB flash drive at `/media/pi/KINGSTON`

But when I look at the log of the execution it says that I have no permissions while creating directories inside `/media/pi/KINGSTON`:

```
Creating /media/pi/KINGSTON/some_dir/another_dir
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/pi/KINGSTON’: Permission denied
```

Here are the permissions on the mounted USB drive:

```
$ getfacl /media/pi/KINGSTON
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/pi/KINGSTON
# owner: pi
# group: pi
user::rwx
group::---
other::---
```

I am suspicious that the job is not executed with `pi` user, because if I use relative path to the script `~` it is not recognized. Also `$USER` variable is not set when echoed from the `cron` job.

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

`cron` may still be using `$LOGNAME` instead of `$USER` and `$HOME` instead of `~`, which shouldn't be used in scripts anyway.

In any case, the error message suggests `/media/pi/KINGSTON` may not even exist. Perhaps the thumb drive is not yet mounted at the moment when `cron` executes your script, or it is being mounted and the mount script didn't apply the permissions yet.

Add some logging to your script (I would go for `mount > /tmp/my.log`) and see what happens. The log file must be created by the `pi` user, and you will see if the thumb drive is really mounted at this point.